# How to mock field of returned object by service method in junit tests?

Tags: java, junit

In Spring Boot I have the service `myService` with method:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    ...
    public FooBarInterface getNewFooBarInstance(boolean x) {
        return x ? new Foo() : new Bar();
    }
}
```

The Foo and Bar have a field:

```
@Value(...)
String loremPath;
```

Which is read from `application.yml` (Foo has value `./src/java/resources/ipsum.txt` and Bar has value `./src/java/resources/dolor.txt`)

Now I want to write test for this service which uses the method, but I want to have different value of `loremPath`, eg. `./src/test/resources/test.txt`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;
    ...
}
```

I tried this:

```
@Mock Foo foo;
@Mock Bar bar;
...
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo,"loremPath",".../test.txt");
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bar,"loremPath",".../test.txt");
```

But this does not work and I have in loremPath a `null` value.

I tried also do this:

```
String testPath = ".../test.txt";
when(foo.getLoremPath()).thenReturn(testPath);
when(bar.getLoremPath()).thenReturn(testPath);
```

But I still have the `null` value there.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the getter on this value.

```java
when(foo.getValue()).thenReturn("mockvalue")
```

Don't forget to use the required runner on your class

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Comment: Which runner do you use on your test class ? Could you show more code in your question  plz

Comment: I've added @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) but still I have null value :(

Comment: Junit 5? If not you can remove extends mockito extension

Answer (score 0):

Mocking can not be done for object which are generated `RunTime` with `Mockito`.

What you need to do is change your class like this, which will allow Mockito to inject mocks.

```
public class MyService {
    ...
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;

    public MyService (Foo foo, Bar bar) {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.bar = bar;
    }      

    public FooBarInterface getNewFooBarInstance(boolean x) {
        return x ? new Foo() : new Bar();
    }
}
```

And then mock to control behavior

```
Mockito.when(foo.getLoremPath()).thenReturn("mockvalue");
```

As already mentioned in other answers, you need to use only one of these.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // with Junit 5
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  // with Junit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Powermockito `whenNew` will solve the issue

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyService.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myService = new MyService();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        // Arrange
        Foo mockedFoo = mock(Foo.class);
        Bar mockedBar = mock(Bar.class);

        whenNew(Foo.class).whithNoArgument().thenReturn(mockedFoo);
        whenNew(Bar.class).whithNoArgument().thenReturn(mockedBar);

        String testPath = ".../test.txt";
        when(mockedFoo.getLoremPath()).thenReturn(testPath);
        when(mockedBar.getLoremPath()).thenReturn(testPath);

        // Act

        // Assert
    }
}
```